# Rails: rollback all transactions if one fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions

So I have this configurations

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :photo_albums

class PhotoAlbum < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :photos
```

and I want to do the following

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
@photo_album = @post.photo_albums.create(name: 'album name')
@photo_urls = params[:photo_urls]
@photo_urls.each do |pu|
 @photo_album.photos.create(url: pu)
end
@post.save
```

Now what I want is that, if @post.save fails then all transactions of photo_albums, photos should rollback.

Comment: use `@post.photo_albums.new( ... )` instead of create because the parent must be persisted first. Then just call `save` on the parent (`@post`) and it will trigger the save of the `photo_album`

Answer (score 2):

Simple.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @photo_album = @post.photo_albums.create(name: 'album name')
  @photo_urls = params[:photo_urls]
  @photo_urls.each do |pu|
    @photo_album.photos.create(url: pu)
  end
  @post.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add an if filter `if @post.save` and write the code block to create `photo_album` and `photos` only if the `@post` is saved

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
if @post.save
  @photo_album = @post.photo_albums.create(name: 'album name')
  @photo_urls = params[:photo_urls]
  @photo_urls.each do |pu|
   @photo_album.photos.create(url: pu)
  end 
else
  # handle @post.save fail
end
```

Comment: I actually meant to rollback all transactions if any save or create fails.

Comment: why do you want to rollback a failing transaction instead of just skipping it .. saves a bunch of db calls

Answer (score 0):

Look into using `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`.

See [this literature](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).